# CloudKit fetch user iTunes backup

Tags: ios, itunes, icloud, cloudkit

I am looking in the documentation of the CloudKit and i am interested in if it is possible to fetch iTunes backup data files from private storage of the CloudKit. Or is it possible to fetch call log data from iCloude ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From CloudKit you can only get the data that you put in yourself (any users by using your app or the api).